# Cannot Use Curve Fitting for Data Set

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I've checked every query on the web, yet I could not find a solution to my problem. I have a very simple set of data, which perfectly fits to a gaussian shape. However, I cannot make a proper fit onto it. Here is my code and result

```
def gauss(x, a, b, c, d): 
    return a * np.exp(-((x-b)/c)**2 + d)
x=np.linspace(np.min(MapCoordX[1,15:25]),np.max(MapCoordX[1,15:25]),100)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, MapCoordX[1,15:25],
                                   mapsurface_norm[xy_in_mapy,15:25])

fit_y        = gauss(x,*popt)
plt.plot(x,fit_y)
plt.plot(MapCoordX[1,15:25],mapsurface_norm[xy_in_mapy,15:25],'o')
plt.show()
```

[Resulted figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCAy3.png)

PS: I also tried with initial guess for better approximation, but whatever I do, the gaussian fit has the exact same shape.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. what are `MapCoordX`, `mapsurface_norm`, `xy_in_mapy` etc? Otherwise, it's hard to help.

Comment: your Gaussian is `a * np.exp(-((x-b)/c)**2 + d)` but should be `a * np.exp(-((x-b)/c)**2)  + d`

Comment: @joni thank you for the help. MapCoordX is the X coordinate of a square region. The region is a 10 micro meter x 10 micro meter area. There is a measurement taken in each coordinate starting from 

(x,y) = (0,0) and proceeding as (x+dx,y) --> (x+10(um),y+10(um))
where dx and dy are the step size. Thus, for a step size of 0.5 micro meter, I will have 21 measurement in each line. 21*21 = 441 measurement for a 100 micro meter squared region. I have 441 number of coordinates representing the region.

Comment: @joni mapsurface_norm is the normalized data of intensities. The measurement is simply collecting light intensity in each coordinate. Thus, light emitting material can be visualised and located within the 100 micro meter region. 

see the image from my data : https://ibb.co/p22MLnn

After I plot the surface of the intensity, I make a user input using the mouse cursor. The selected point will be plotted as intensity versus wavelength, keeping the y component constant. I want to see the behaviour of my intensity only along x direction. I want to make gauss fit along x axis.

Comment: @joni xy_in_mapy is the y point of the cursor selection.

Comment: @mikuszefski not worked, it shows a straight line when I do it :(

Comment: ...well you still need some starting values like `a0 = max(y)-min(y)` or `d0=min(y)`, the mean you can get from the weighted sum, like `sum ( x * (y-d0) ) / sum (y -d0 )` and the standard deviation accordingly